# AutomationId for TabBar items not getting set in Android with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, appium, appium-android

So I have the following code:

```
<TabBar Route="Dashboard">
   <Tab Title="Dashboard" AutomationId="DashboardId">
      //more codes here
   </Tab>
   <Tab AutomationId="AddNewId">
      //more codes here
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Statistics" AutomationId="StatisticsId">
      //more codes here
   </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Note that in my `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate()` I have set up the following:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ViewInitializedEventArgs e) => {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.View.AutomationId))
    {
        e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.AutomationId;
    }
};
```

This works perfectly with my other elements except for the `TabBar` items. Somehow the TabBar items are getting the `Title` property and setting is at the `accessibilityId/content-dec`.

[image]

Anyone knows why this is and how can I make it so it will get the right `AutomationId`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with `AutomationId` on Android.

The underlying problem is discussed in [Android - Using AutomationId prevents TalkBack screenreader accessibility](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1529):

> Xamarin.Forms "borrows" the ContentDescription property on Android for Automation IDs. These IDs polute Android's TalkBack accessibility tree, making apps almost impossible to navigate.

> This means you can support test automation or accessibility, not both. Our app needs to support both.

In the case of `Tab`s, presumably Xamarin code is doing what you see: copying `Title` to `content-desc`, so that Android text readers will speak it.

The suggested work-around is to write custom renderer(s) that do what you need. Described in a [comment by codingL3gend](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1529#issuecomment-437213503) :

> i was able to find a work around to this issue by creating a customrenderer and respective custom component to allow for overriding the native android method(s) that get triggered when accessibility events are fired. you will need to create some bindable properties on your custom component that you can access in the custom renderer to allow for setting the content description value to what you want but that's simple enough.
>
> this method gets triggered in the control/custom renderer whenever an accessibility event is fired
>
> ```
> public override bool OnRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(Android.Views.View child, AccessibilityEvent e)
>   {
>          if (AccessibilityHandler.IsAccessibilityEnabled(_context) && child != null)
>          {
>                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_automationId) && _automationId.Equals(child.ContentDescription))
>                 {
>                     child.ContentDescription = $"{_automationName} {_helpText}";
>                 }
>          }
>
>          return base.OnRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(child, e);
> }
> ```
>
> then you can set the contentDescription value of the control/custom renderer back to what the automationId value was originally when the control/custom renderer is detached from the view.
>
> ```
> protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
>   {
>         base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
>
>         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_automationId))
>         {
>             Control.ContentDescription = _automationId;
>         }
>   }
> ```
>
> helper class
>
> ```
> public static class AccessibilityHandler
>     {
>         public static bool IsAccessibilityEnabled(Context context)
>         {
>             var accessibility = (AccessibilityManager)context.GetSystemService(MainActivity.AccessibilityService);
>
>             return accessibility?.GetEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(Android.AccessibilityServices.FeedbackFlags.Spoken)?.Count > 0;
>         }
>     }
> ```

---

**If you only need AutomationId during testing, or you can live with the effect this has on Accessibility Screen Readers (esp. it won't be multi-lingual),** then you could make a much simpler custom renderer for use when testing.

Put this in your custom renderer (if isn't `Tab`, then change `<Tab>` to appropriate Xamarin class):

```
protected override void OnElementChanged( ElementChangedEventArgs<Tab> e )
{
    base.OnElementChanged( e );

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        // Removing previous element.
        // TBD: Remove obsolete references. (usually not needed)
    }
    if (Element == null)
        // Going away with no replacement.
        return;

    UpdateAutomationId();
}

void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Element.AutomationId))
    {
        UpdateAutomationId();
    }
}

void UpdateAutomationId()
{
    var _automationId = Element.AutomationId;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_automationId))
    {
        Control.ContentDescription = _automationId;
    }
}
```